# Object property that can be getter or function

Tags: javascript

I am coding a chainable library and I want the API to allow calling part of the chain as static values (with a default value) and sometimes as functions, so parameters could be pass to them.

### Simplified example:

```js
var obj = {};
var chainCache = [];

Reflect.defineProperty(obj, 'color', {
  get(){
    chainCache.push('red');
    return obj;
  }
})

Reflect.defineProperty(obj, 'background', {
  get(){
    chainCache.push('black');
    return obj;
  }
})

Reflect.defineProperty(obj, 'end', {
  value(){
    var value = chainCache.join(" ");
    chainCache.length = 0;
    return value;
  }
})

console.log( obj.color.background.end() ) // red black
```

This is a very simplified example and in reality I would also like to include an ability in the above "API" to optionally use the **same** `color` key, like this:

```
obj.color.background.end()          // current API (great)
obj.color('#FF0').background.end()  // optionally call "color" as function
obj.color().background.end()        // bad API, I do not want this
```

Can `color` be both *function* and *property* at the same time, depending how it is called?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: You will need to make `obj` a function.

Answer (score 0):

I took a harder look at this than I intended. It looks like with the advent of [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) this is possible. Building on your example:

```
let chainCache = [];
let obj = {
    color: new Proxy(()=>{}, {
        get: (target, prop) => {
            chainCache.push("red");
            if(prop === "background") {
                chainCache.push("black");
                return { end: obj.end };
            }
        },
        apply: (target, prop, args) => {
            if(args.length > 0) {
                chainCache.push(args.pop());
            } else {
                throw new Error("color expects argument if called like function");
            }
            return { background: new Proxy(()=>{}, {
                get: (target,prop) => { chainCache.push("black"); return obj.end;}
            })};
        }
    }),
    end: () => {
        let value = chainCache.join(" ");
        chainCache = [];
        return value;
    }
};
console.log(obj.color.background.end());
console.log(obj.color("#FF0").background.end());
console.log(obj.color().background.end());
```

In the debug console you get:

```
red black
#FF0 black
Error: color expects argument if called like function
```

Essentially color is a proxy that wraps an anonymous arrow function, if color is accessed like a property the `get()` trap gets called, if color gets accessed as a function the `apply()` trap gets called. This allows for a certain degree of meta-programming like you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah I'm already using proxies in my code btw, but this isn't exactly what I want. the code must not use the default value if an argument was supplied, so the *second* example is actually a bug. Also, you should probably write `return obj` instead of `return { end: obj.end };` You've also merged both `backgound` and `color` but they should probably be separate because I would want to be able to do the same trick of conditionally passing parameters on every "key" of `obj`

Comment: I've updated my example. The only reason "red" was showing up is that in the proxy called by a function I was returning the property. Accessing that property caused the default value to be added. You can add additional proxies as I did above to avoid that. I was only treating your example like an example, I wasn't trying to design a fully functioned API, so I did take shortcuts to get the syntax you wanted to see. This should answer the original question of whether or not it is possible to treat a property of an object as either a function or property depending on how it's called.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make `obj` a function.

A function is just an object and can have properties as well - `obj.color` must return a function (for `obj.color()`) that has properties (for `obj.color.background`).

But no, when the getter is accessed you don't know yet whether it will be used for a method invocation or not - `obj.color()` is a property access *plus* a function call.

```
var chainCache = [];
var obj = Object.defineProperties(function obj(...args) {
  chainCache.push(args);
  return obj;
}, {
  color: {
    get() {
      chainCache.push('color');
      return obj;
    }
  },
  background: {
    get() {
      chainCache.push('background');
      return obj;
    }
  },
  end: {
    value: function() {
      var res = chainCache.reduce((acc, val) =>
        Array.isArray(val)
          ? `${acc}(${val.join(',')})`
          : `${acc}.${val}`
      , "obj");
      chainCache.length = 0;
      return res;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I always very much appreciate your input. I would like to say that I am asking this in regard to a project I put up last night [console colors](https://github.com/yairEO/console-colors) in which I wan't to empower a `color` method to return a random color if no color parameter was supplied, but to keep the "nice" syntax of not forcing the user to use a function `()` braces

Comment: @vsync Micheals answer is a bit overcomplicated, and tailored very specifically to his example call pattern. You don't need a proxy at all when you know the available properties beforehand, using getters is totally equivalent then.

Comment: @vsync I don't understand where "console colors" would need something that could do both - you currently have either `console.green.log()` or `console.random.log()`, right?

Comment: I want to get rid of `random` and change it to `color` and then the user can optionally pass a parameter or simply use it at a property: `console.color.big.bold.log()` to get a random color. seems like a nicer API no?

Comment: I agree the over complication which of this might not be worth it, but i was just curious if such is possible in javascript and had asked here

Comment: @vsync `console.color("green").log()` does not seem to be a nicer API than `console.green.log()` to me.

Comment: @vsync In any case, what you need is to collect all the property names and arguments in an array, and then evaluate that in the end in the `log` method. Only there you can distinguish between `console.color.log()` and `console.color().log()`, you cannot do the distinction in the getter of `.color`. (Regardless whether you use a getter or proxy to detect the property access).

Comment: Not `console.color("green").log()` obviously but a color which isn't in my default scheme: `console.color("#A5F200").log()` for example. This gives maximum flexibility